# How to get redirect url in Vuejs from Laravel/Passport

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-passport

I'm building a simple login in `Vue.js` where my backend in `laravel/passport` for authentication method. Before implementing `passport` I was having a manual `login controller` which get the `redirect url from session` something like this:

Suppose my Routes was `Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@postLogin)` now in the controller I was computing something like this:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, User::$login_validation_rules);
    $data = $request->only('email', 'password');
    $intended_url = Session::get('url.intended', url('/'));
    Session::forget('url.intended');

   // Authentication codes

    return $intended_url, $user;
}
```

Now I was taking this in Vue file like this:

```
axios.post('/login', postData).then(response => {
     // computation of objects
    window.location.href = '/dashboard';
})
```

Now my url as I'm using `Laravel\passport` has been changed to `axios.post('/oauth/token', postData)`

Can someone guide me how to add `intended_url`  to this response, Is it possible to get in same `axios request` or I have to call another `axios request`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the return to a Json object that's easy to parse and Axios should be able to be set up to automatically parse it.

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
  $this->validate($request, User::$login_validation_rules);
  $data = $request->only('email', 'password');
  $intended_url = Session::get('url.intended', url('/'));
  Session::forget('url.intended');

  // Authentication codes

  return \Response::json([ 'url' => $intended_url, 'user' => $user], 200);
}
```

This will create a Json object with the pertinent information and pass it with the correct headers. in JS it should be something similar to this:

```
axios.post('/login', postData)
.then(
  response => {
    let JsonObj = JSON.parse(response.body)

    // computation of objects
    window.location.href = JsonObj.url;
  }
)
```

you may have to do some tests to see what response is returning and go from there.

Comment: that's not the question, question is laravel passport has there own url for authentication that is fixed to `/oauth/token` I'm not using `/login` and `postLogin function` in `LoginController` anymore for authentication.